# Can resources be extracted from a compiled iPhone app? If yes, how can they be secured?

Tags: iphone, xml, security, resources

Can resources be extracted from a compiled iPhone app that is released to the iTunes store? I'm particularly interested in the security of XML files... if I have copyrighted data in an XML document in my resource directory, how likely is it for someone to extract that information and paste it around the internet?

If it's as easy as using a resource editor, how can that data be secured?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the user take the resource from the iPhone Apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753213/can-the-user-take-the-resource-from-the-iphone-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, resources can definitely be extracted. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753213/can-the-user-take-the-resource-from-the-iphone-apps/2753392#2753392)

If it's important to you, encrypting the data is a good idea, as medopal said.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt/decrypt the data on write/read.

Take a look at `CommonCrypto` class.